How to write a condition in a (A . B) dotted pair in use-package key :bind data
For the configuration of vterm I have in my Emacs config a snippet like this:
(use-package vterm
    :config
    (setq vterm-shell "xonsh")
    :bind (:map vterm-mode-map
                ("<M-right>" . vterm-send-C-e)
                ...
                ))

Now I want to make the string "<M-right>" to be diffrenent depeding on a condition: For Macs it should be "<A-right>" , for all others systems (Linux) it should be "<M-right>".
So I tried:
(use-package vterm
    :config
    (setq vterm-shell "xonsh")
    :bind (:map vterm-mode-map
                ((cond ((eq system-type 'darwin)
                        "<A-right>")
                       (t ;; linux
                        "<M-right>")) . vterm-send-C-e)
                ...
                ))

but I get a big syntax error on start up. So with my naive approach the result of the cond function is not properly inserted in the dotted pair.
How can I do this right?

use-package is a macro, so the solution will be specific to however use-package handles those particular arguments.  I don't use it, so I don't know.  You should read its documentation to find out.  Outside of a macro, the general answer is that the lisp reader reads (A . B) as a cons cell -- and @shynur has just posted an answer showing the simplest way to create a cons cell at eval time.  The other common approach is a backquote/comma pairing \(A . ,B)to haveBevaluated at eval time.  These methods may or may not be the answer in your case, depending onuse-package`.

@phils I deleted that answer for the same reason - forms that appear at that location do not appear to be evaluated. https://github.com/jwiegley/use-package?tab=readme-ov-file#key-binding.

In that case, I'll add the general info here: (cons A B) creates (at eval time) a cons cell with a car of the evaluated A, and a cdr of the evaluated B.  (But within the arguments to a macro call, nothing gets evaluated without the macro's say so, so you have to establish what it does.)

BTW, @halloleo if you need a workaround then just don't use :bind to define that key binding.  It looks like the argument to :config must get evaluated, so you can undoubtedly call (define-key ...) in there.

@phils Thanks for all the comments! They made the situation a lot clearer to me.

Maybe you don't need to do that at all.
Have a look at these variables mac-command-modifier, and mac-option-modifier
for example, I have this in my config:
(when (eq system-type 'darwin)
  (setq mac-command-modifier 'meta))


Good idea, thanks! -- Will look into this to unify my key configs.
